# Azure AD Identity doesn't seem to provide email for auto-linking Umbraco User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, umbraco, azure-active-directory

I've setup the Azure Active Directory Auth configuration and sigining in through our Azure AD works perfectly.

I've modified the AuthenticationOptions so the External Sign in automatically links the accounts, but it seems like the Azure AD doesn't provide an e-mailaddress to link.

```
adOptions.SetExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(new ExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(
            autoLinkExternalAccount:true));
```

It gives me the following exception

```
The requested provider (https://sts.windows.net/{id}) has not provided an email address, the account cannot be linked.
```

Is there a way to make this work? It works perfectly without the `SetExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions` setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out the `Name` claim was also the e-mail address, so I had to intercept the Notifications to pass in the `Name` claim as the `Email` claim:

```
adOptions.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
            {
                var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                    id.AuthenticationType,
                    System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                    System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role);

                //Here I added the Name as E-mail claim
                nid.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, id.Name));
                nid.AddClaim(id.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
                nid.AddClaim(id.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName));
                nid.AddClaim(id.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name));

                n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(nid, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Yeah it is, I've changed it around a bit in production code but the core is still the same and running. I have not tested it in the latest release (7.6.1) yet.

Comment: I did something similar but added the claim to the exists if it didn't exist                                    //Check if email exists
                                    if (id.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email) == null)
                                    {
                                        id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, id.Name));
                                    }

Answer (score 2):

Based on the description, it seems that you want the token endpoint issue the `email` claim.

As far as I know, The Azure AD V2.0 support this claim by using the `email` scope. You can refer it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/). However, based on the test, it only support for the **Microsoft Account** at present. If you also want it to support the work or school account, you may submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and you can go into azure portal and under

Azure Active Direction ->  App Registrations -> Your app

Select Token configuration and "Add optional claim" select "ID" and "email" and "Add"

This then returns the email as part of the token.